# How can I iterate through the indices of the list?

Tags: python

I am trying to compute three lists for example

`M =[[3, 0, 2, -8, -8], [5, 3, 2, 2, 3], [2, 5, 2, 1, 4]]`

I want to first sum  every first value in the list `x=3+5+2`

and the rest values in all the lists add them together as `y`

finally the `difference of absolute value of x-y which is 10 - 8`

and again sum  every first two values in the list `x=3+5+2+0+3+5`

and the rest values in all the lists add them together as `y`

finally the `difference of absolute value of x-y which is 18 - 0`

again the same process until the last value in the list

lastly If difference is  the minimum stored value, set the minimum value to difference and the minimum index to index, and finally return the slices found by getting the minimum value

for this example slices found is `list1=[3,5,2] list2=[0,2,-8,-8,3,2,2,3,2,5,2,1,4]` i calculated it manually but i couldn't implement it

```
 def Vertical_UpperMatrix(M):
        ds=range(5)
        diffList = [(abs(sum(ds[:i]) - sum(ds[i:]))) for i in range(3)]
        return diffList.index(min(diffList))
 M=[[3, 0, 2, -8, -8], [5, 3, 2, 2, 3], [2, 5, 2, 1, 4]]
```

Comment: Please add some punctuation if you will, just so that we have the incentive to read what you have written.

Comment: i'm sorry its my first time in stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is not clear in my question? So i can explain it better

Comment: Almost _everything_ in your question is unclear.

Comment: Pretend you're writing an essay for your final exam in English, and your English teacher is really really strict about grammar. This question is one long run-on sentence and it's pretty unintelligible.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope its better now

Comment: Much better, now I see your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in EST timezone, so at the time this answer is written, it is 2:40am. But I am taking time to answer, basically to repay your willingness to improve.

We will use a library called `numpy`. If you don't have `numpy` on your machine, please Google-Search how you can install it on your OS. It is important for your career onwards, and you will see why.

First, create your `numpy` array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = np.array([[3, 0, 2, -8, -8], [5, 3, 2, 2, 3], [2, 5, 2, 1, 4]])
>>> l
array([[ 3,  0,  2, -8, -8],
       [ 5,  3,  2,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  5,  2,  1,  4]])
```

Now you can access the first column by doing

```
>>> l[:, 0]
array([3, 5, 2])
```

The first row can be accessed by

```
>>> l[0, :]
array([ 3,  0,  2, -8, -8])
```

The first row from the second element to the fourth element by

```
>>> l[0, 1:4]
array([ 0,  2, -8])
```

Based on all the features above, the target function you want is basically this:

```
>>> d = 1
>>> np.abs(np.sum(l[:, 0:d]) - np.sum(l[:, d:]))
2
```

`d` is your dividing index. Now you can iterate over `d` in a for loop.

I suggest you learn about at least `numpy` and `scipy` if you plan to carry on your career with `Python`.

Comment: thanks but still how can i get the values of (np.sum(l[:, 0:d]) and np.sum(l[:, d:]) that got 2 to put it in list1 and list2?

Comment: Store them somewhere in your for loop. You need to finish the last bit of your homework yourself.